# The viewing session is not available or has expired with Tomcat 7

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, birt, tomcat7

I installed the BIRT Viewer in Apache Tomcat 7, but I have this error when running a report on the application:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The viewing session is not available or has expired
```

I have made same steps in another PC and everything went well.

I read many posts that talk about it, but neither of the solutions have resolved the problem.
The main one was [this](http://www.birt-exchange.org/org/forum/index.php/topic/15211-the-viewing-session-not-available/page__p__60445&#entry60445).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though application worked fine in Firefox and Chrome, I have experienced same error in IE browser only when report is opened within iframe and only when frameset is used.

There are two ways to fix this:

1. Reduce security in IE to low or add the site to trusted.
2. Before opening report in iframe, call Ajax function to some test report.

   For ex:

   ```
   ajaxRequest.open("GET","http://localhost:8080/birt/frameset?__report=test.rptdesign");
   ```

I have to opt for second option, because in my situation I cannot ask my users to reduce security or trust our site.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue but my problem was the url-path of report, look:

My Iframe:

```
<iframe src="#{var.ipserver}/birt/frameset?__report=report/report/balance/balance_card.rptdesign" width="900" height="600"/>
```

When the iframe was rendered in the browser the url was:

```
<iframe src="http://192.168.0.111//birt/frameset?__report=report/balance/balance_card.rptdesign" width="900" height="600"></iframe>
```

there is double slash after IP, this was the problem, when I fixed it (as you can see below) it worked!!

```
  <iframe src="#{var.ipserver}birt/frameset?__report=report/report/balance/balance_card.rptdesign" width="900" height="600"/>
```